# Die Schule in Deutschland zu besuchen wäre für mich auch möglich. Komma nach "besuchen"?

Tags: spelling, infinitive, comma

> Die Schule in Deutschland zu besuchen wäre für mich auch möglich

In diesem Satz muss man ein Komma zwischen besuchen und wäre setzen?
Sonst ist der Satz richtig, oder?

Comment: Sonst: Mach einen Punkt zum Schluß.

Answer (score 2):

*Die Schule in Deutschland zu besuchen* ist eine Infinitivgruppe.

[§ 75 des amtlichen Regelwerks](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6201#par75):

> Infinitivgruppen grenzt man mit Komma ab, wenn eine der folgenden
>   Bedingungen erfüllt ist.
>
> (1) die Infinitivgruppe ist mit *um, ohne, statt, anstatt, außer, als* eingeleitet (...)
>
> (2) die Infinitivgruppe hängt von einem Substantiv ab (...)
>
> (3) die Infinitivgruppe hängt von einem Korrelat oder einem Verweiswort ab (...)
>
> E1: Wenn ein bloßer Infinitiv vorliegt, können in den Fallgruppen (2) und (3) die Kommas weggelassen werden, sofern keine Missverständnisse entstehen (...)
>
> E2: In den Fällen, die nicht durch § 75(1) bis (3) geregelt sind, kann ein Komma gesetzt werden, um die Gliederung deutlich zu machen bzw. um Missverständnisse auszuschließen (...)

Gemäß E2 **kann** im Beispiel also ein Komma gesetzt werden, um die Gliederung deutlich zu machen. (Ich persönlich würde es setzen.) Auch ansonsten ist der Satz korrekt.

Würde man den Satz zu *Es wäre für mich auch möglich, die Schule in Deutschland zu besuchen* umstellen, **müsste** man gemäß Absatz 3 zwingend ein Komma setzen (Korrelat-*es*).

Answer (score 0):

Nachdem die Rechtschreibreform von 1996 und deren nachgeschobene kleinere Änderungen eine Reihe von Kommaregeln verändert haben (oft von **muss** auf **kann**), habe ich nicht mehr dieselbe traumwandlerische Sicherheit - die eher auf Sprachgefühl denn auf exakter Kenntnis der Regeln beruhte, aber nahezu immer richtig war - wie zuvor.
Gefühlt würde ich dort ein Komma setzen, aber ich hege den Verdacht, dass das einer der geänderten Fälle und somit nunmehr ein "kann" ist. Falsch ist ein Komma hier aber jedenfalls nicht.

Comment: ... nicht mehr dieselbe Sicherheit verloren? ;)

Comment: @Olafant tja, wenn man beim Schreiben mehrere gleichbedeutende, aber unterschiedlich konstruierte, Formulierungen im Kopf hat... Gerade bei längeren Einschüben kann es dann passieren, das die Teile vor und nach dem Einschub irgendwie nicht so ganz zusammenpassen.